# Significance of 99% of variance covered by the first component in PCA

Tags: matlab, pca

What does it mean/signify when the first component covers for more than 99% of the total variance in PCA analysis ? 
I have a feature vector of size 500X1000 on which I used Matlab's pca function which returns [coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained]. The variable 'explained' returns the percentage of variance covered by each component.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. I found that the most features that explained components always have very large value, which can be checked through biplot() function. So, I have normalized the features and got the normal results now. So, you can have a try normalization for rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `explained` tells you how accurately you could represent the data by just using that principal component. In your case it means that just using the main principal component, you can describe very accurately (to a 99%) the data.

Lets make a 2D example. Imagine you have data that is `100x2` and you do PCA.

the result could be something like this (taken from the internets)

[image]

This data will give you an `explained` value for the first principal component (PCA 1st dimension big green arrow in the figure) of around 90%.

What does it means?

It means that if you project all your data to that line, you will reconstruct the points with 90% of accuracy (of course, you will loose the information in the PCA 2nd dimension direction).

In your example, with 99% it visually means that almost all the points in blue are laying on the big green arrow, with very little variation in the small green arrow direction.

Of course it is way more difficult to visualize with 1000 dimensions instead of 2, but I hope you understand.

Comment: @user1791066 It meas they are closely situated NEXT to the big green arrow, not among them.

Comment: @user1791066 Yes. The problem is that with 1000 dimensions the human brain can not imagine the "shape" of the green arrow. But in fact what you have when you do PCA is 1000 arrows that cross 1000 dimensions. And one of them (the first one) is the biggest "green arrow" (no superhero puns intended). All your data are in that 1000 dimensional green arrow. As this is very difficult to visualize, examples are usually given in 2D (as the image above).

Comment: So, if I replace each n-dimensional point with the first component(which is a linear combination of the n dimensions of the point) then I would lose only 1% of the total information?

Comment: @user1791066 Exactly! Basically what that result is telling you: Instead of having a 500x1000 matrix, if you have a 500x1 matrix, and then you multiply that by the fist PC (1x1000 size) you will get a 500x1000 new data matrix that will be 99% correlated to the original data (and you save tons of memory and computational effort!)

Comment: thanks a lot! I know this is slightly off the topic but if I replace the 1000 features with 1 feature my classifier accuracy drops from 80% to 30% even though I have retained 99% variance. What could be causing it?

Comment: @user1791066 No idea! Thats a whole new question. Its weird because it should not happen. How did you calculate the new 500x1 values? anyway, better open anew question with more detail.